# Null object reference error, while attempting to invoke virtual method at Recycler View

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to achieve Recycler View to list the documents that are uploaded in the real-time database (Firebase) with the help of a custom adapter.

There are no errors during the compilation, but when tried to open the activity on the app it simply reverts back or displays the error message.

Here is the code ---

```
RecyclerView upload_ai;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_ai_bg);

    DatabaseReference databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    databaseReference.child("AI_Unit_1");
    databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

            String fileName= dataSnapshot.getKey();
            String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            ((ai_unit_1_recyclerview)upload_ai.getAdapter()).update(fileName,url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
    RecyclerView upload_ai= findViewById(R.id.ai_upload_unit_1);
    upload_ai.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager( ai_bg.this));
    ai_unit_1_recyclerview myAdapter= new ai_unit_1_recyclerview(upload_ai,ai_bg.this,new ArrayList<String>(),new ArrayList<String>());
    upload_ai.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}
```

Here's the LOGCAT of the issue ---

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.getAdapter()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.ngitstudentportal.ai_bg$1.onChildAdded(ai_bg.java:36)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ChildEventRegistration.fireEvent(ChildEventRegistration.java:79)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8030)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
```

Comment: I think this line `RecyclerView upload_ai= findViewById(R.id.ai_upload_unit_1);` may be the issue try using `upload_ai=findViewById(R.id.ai_upload_unit_1);` instead and putting this right after your `setContentView`.

Comment: The issue is that your not using the field for your `RecyclerView` as you're declaring a different `upload_ai`, so when `onChildAdded` gets called it uses your empty field instead of the new `upload_ai`.

Comment: Please show us the layout file as well. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Hey everyone thank you for responding, I have found out that I have made many mistakes in the code and I'm trying to resolve everything. Thank you @AliasCartellano, your suggestions helped me a lot to fix multiple issues.

Comment: @AlexMamo thank you for responding, but even sharing the layout file wouldn't help, as I have noticed my code is wrong. I will reach out for your help and suggestions, If I face any issues in the future code changes